# Mac bootcamp boots under VMWare fusion but not normally

Tags: mac, boot, windows-8.1, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I have a mac bootcamp partition running windows 8.1 that used to work perfectly.  I've been using it for about 9 months exclusively under vmware fusion and all has been fine.  I have recently however needed to use OpenCL and so I tried booting it up normally.  However it gets to the point where it would show the windows logo and then shows the rotating circle of dots.  It then never gets passed this.  I have left the thing over night and it has still not progressed past this point.

Does anyone have any idea how I fix this?

I've tried disabling the various boot checks and this hasn't helped.  I've tried repairing with windows recovery and this didn't help.  I've also tried enabling the boot log ... and no boot log was written.

I'm at a total loss of how to fix this.  The machine is a mid 2014 macbook pro retina (the highest end model).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you shut down the VM completely before trying to boot to it in BC, rather than just suspending it? idk about VMWare, but for Parallels that's essential.

Comment: You can't hibernate a VMWare fusion bootcamp VM, presumably for exactly this reason.

Comment: Ah, OK, wasn't aware of that. You can with Parallels, so long as you don't need it from BC.